Non-injective closure of injective unbounded operator
Let $A\colon H\to H$ be an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with domain dom$(A)$. Suppose that $A$ is injective. Suppose that $A$ is closable (or symmetric, even).
Question: Does this imply that the closure $\bar A$ is also injective from dom$(\bar A)\to H$?
Thoughts: I don't see why there can't be a sequence $v_i\in$ dom$(A)$ with limit $v\in$ dom($\bar A$), such that $Av_i\neq 0$ yet $Av=0$. But somehow I can't think of a counter-example.

This provides a counter example.

@jd27 Nice example, thank you!
